# How can I make my API response more fast?

Tags: xdebug, cakephp-3.x

My requisitions are take a lot of time to return a response. What can I do to reduce this time?

I already tried different configuration of caches but no success.

[image]

Is possible return this response more fast?

Comment: Are those 37 seconds?! There's clearly some unusual bottleneck somewhere then. I'd suggest to use a proper profiler like xdebug to figure where exactly the time is spent.

Comment: Can you show the code for the offensive API endpoint? We can't give a useful answer without observing the issue. A picture of bad response times isn't particularly useful.

Comment: Yeah, I will post my controller endpoint.

Comment: @ndm Thank you for suggest.